# I encountered this problem when I used plt.pcolormesh and stft in scipy

Tags: python-3.x

```
data = torch.load("F:\A01T.pt")
data = data[0,0,:]
print(data.shape)
fs = 250
f,t,Zxx = signal.stft(data,fs=fs,window='hann', nperseg=256, noverlap=None, nfft=None, detrend=False, return_onesided=True, boundary='zeros', padded=True, axis=-1)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx), vmin=0, vmax=np.max(np.abs(Zxx)), shading='gouraud')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

this is the outcome:

torch.Size([22, 751])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/PythonCode/Pg_EEG_DA_SNN/Test/path.py", line 68, in 
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx), vmin=0, vmax=np.max(np.abs(Zxx)), shading='gouraud')
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2757, in pcolormesh
**({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 1601, in inner
return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 6157, in pcolormesh
X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 5726, in _pcolorargs
numRows, numCols = C.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

What causes this problem？
Is it a version problem？